# can we make enterprise AD transparent to the existence of local kerberos mechanism?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, authorization, kerberos, rbac

we already have users in enterprise AD and we want kerberos ticket to be generated for these users from local kerberos server instead of the kerberos service  in the AD itself.

the intent of this we want to make enterprise AD transparent to the exixtence of kerberos mechanism

the approach that we are thinking is--

say we have 3 boxes:

1. Enterprise AD
2. local AD with embedded kerberos
3. Role based access control box

Flow that we are thinking--

1. RBAC box will receive user request for authentication and authorization
2. in place of forwarding request to enterprise AD , RBAC box forwards request to our local AD with embedded kerberos.
3. now, local AD with embedded kerberos queries enterprise AD for user authentication.
4. on success of authentication, local AD with kerberos generates ticket and sends response back to RBAC box which either allows/denies the services to user.

we don't know if this could be done, if possible please guide us or suggest approach for achieving the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If enterprise AD and local ADs are organized as forrest, then it might be possible to realize this scenario using the "cross-realm authentication": https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178%28v=ws.10%29.aspx